Can we overload a PostMapping in SpringBoot?
Let's say I have two objects : Person and Stranger which extends Person:
public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
}

public class Stranger extends Person {
    private String hairColor;
    private String tshirtColor;
}

I want to print an image based on these object by calling /print in my REST API.
I already did it with the Person object:
@PostMapping(value = "/print", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String print(@RequestBody Person person) {
    return this.personService.print(person);
}

What I'd like to do, is overload the print because I want to be able to give the Stranger object as argument.
So is it possible to just make something like this? Or is it a bad practice, will it compile too?
@PostMapping(value = "/print", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String print(@RequestBody Stranger stranger) {
    return this.personService.print(stranger);
}

EDIT: I forgot to say that I saw I can do it with RequestParam (https://tomaytotomato.com/overloading-rest-endpoints-on-spring-boot-2/), but I'm using RequestBody

If you want to put both of those POST mappings on the same controller then no, it will not work.  You can, however, change your request body to just be a JsonObject and it will accept both a Person and a Stranger.  In your controller, determine if it's a person or a stranger, create your objects before calling the personService.print().

Your code will compile just fine since you wrote an overloading for print method and that is totally legit to Java.
At runtime, though, you will get a BeanCreationException since you cannot have more than one @PostMapping on the same path (specified in the value attribute):
without further narrowing Spring won't know which one to use, and so it will throw the exception complaining about "Ambiguous mapping".
If you want it to work, you could use headers to narrow your mappings, like this:
@PostMapping(value = "/print", headers = "Type=person", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public String print(@RequestBody Person person) {
    return this.personService.print(person);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/print", headers = "Type=stranger", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public String print(@RequestBody Stranger stranger) {
    return this.personService.print(stranger);
}

When you make the request to /print endpoint add an HTTP Header named Type and valorize it with person or stranger if you want to call the print method with Person or Stranger parameter, respectively.

Alternatively, if you want to have just one print method in your controller with a Person parameter, you could use Jackson's JsonTypeInfo annotation to have  polymorphic types, like this:
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Stranger.class, name = "Stranger"),
})
public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
}

and then add a "type" parameter on the JSON Object you send in the request to specify dinamically the class to use (Person or Stranger) like this:
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "hairColor": "black",
    "tshirtColor": "orange",
    "type": "Stranger"
}

